# Lombok's @With annotation on concrete class does not apply on abstract parent's class fields

Tags: spring, inheritance, constructor, abstract-class, lombok

Using Java spring boot, I'm trying to inherit from a super class and implement Lombok's @With annotation on child classes

However, I am not able to use Lombok's `.with(property)` methods on the abstract's class fields in order to get a new object of the child's instance.

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@With
@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends Parent {
    private float a;
    private int b;
    
    public Child(float a,int b, int c) {
        super(c);
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
}
```

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@With
public abstract class Parent {
    protected int c;

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Lombok can only automatically implement the [@Width](https://projectlombok.org/features/With) methods for fields of concrete classes, since part of the implementation is the instantiation of the class. This only works for specific classes. For fields of abstract classes you have to implement the method manually. Did you take that into account?

The following works and can be generated automatically, therefore lombok can use the constructor of the class directly to instantiate:

```
public Child withA(float a) {
    return this.a == a ? this : new Child(a, this.b, this.c);
}
```

The following does not work because the class is abstract:

```
public Parent withC(int c) {
    return this.c == c ? this : /* WHAT TO DO HERE?!; new Parent(...) IS WRONG */;
}
```